# Monads in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm new to Monads and was trying to write an add function and I'm unsure why this doesn't work. When using monads, is there a specific way you need to return a value?

```
monadd :: (Monad m, Num b) => m b -> m b -> m b
monadd mx my = mx >>= (\x -> my >>= (\y -> (x + y)))
```

Comment: What result do you expect from `monadd [1,2] [3,4,5]` ?

Answer (score 9):

You want to use `pure` (more general form of `return`)

```hs
monadd :: Monad m => Num a => m a -> m a -> m a
monadd mx my = mx >>= (\x -> my >>= (\y -> pure (x + y)))
```

The right-hand side (continuation) of `>>=` must always return a monadic action. But when you add `x + y :: a` you have a number. You need `pure (x + y) :: m a` to turn it into a monadic action:

```hs
monadd :: Monad m => Num a => m a -> m a -> m a
monadd mx my = mx >>= (\x -> my >>= (\y -> pure (x + y)))
              ^^^       ^   ^^^       ^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
              m a       a   m a       a    m a
```

You can equivalently write it in `do`-notation

```hs
monadd :: Monad m => Num a => m a -> m a -> m a
monadd mx my = do
  x <- mx
  y <- my
  pure (x + y)
```

Actually. This doesn't require `Monad`. `Applicative` (n-ary lifting) is sufficient:

```hs
monadd :: Applicative m => Num a => m a -> m a -> m a
monadd = liftA2 (+)
```

Reminder that `Functor` lifts a unary function and `Applicative` lifts constants and n-ary functions (where `liftA0 = pure` and `liftF1 = fmap`):

```hs
liftA0 :: Applicative f => (a)                -> (f a)
liftF1 :: Functor     f => (a -> b)           -> (f a -> f b)
liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c)      -> (f a -> f b -> f c)
liftA3 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c -> d) -> (f a -> f b -> f c -> f d)
```

You only need `Monad` when there is a *dependency* between the computations. Notice that in your case the `my` computation does not dependent on the result of the `mx` computation.

If `m b` depended on the output of `m a` it would become `a -> m b`. Then `Monad` is required:

```hs
dependency :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> (a -> m b) -> m c
dependency (·) as bs = do
  a <- as
  b <- bs a
  pure (a · b)
```

Answer (score 7):

> When using monads, is there a specific way you need to Return a value?

Yes, you will need to wrap `x` and `y` back in a monadic context, with [**`return :: Monad m => a -> m a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return), so:

```
monadd :: (Monad m, Num b) => m b -> m b -> m b
monadd mx my = mx >>= (\x -> my >>= return (x+y)))
```

Since the two operations of the monad `mx` and `my` operate independently of each other however, `Applicative` is sufficient, you can implement this as:

```
monadd :: (Applicative f, Num b) => f b -> f b -> f b
monadd mx my = (+) <$> mx <*> my
```

or through [**`liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2):

```
monadd :: (Applicative f, Num b) => f b -> f b -> f b
monadd = liftA2 (+)
```

Comment: Please don't say “the two monads”. There's only one monad involved here.